# COM+ Objects with IIS 7.0

Tags: visual-studio-2010, iis-7, com+

I am converting PPT to images using ASP.NET code. When i run my code Directly (no IIS 7.0 involved) its runs perfect. But when i configure my application to IIS 7.0 and then run the application its giving me the following error:

```
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {91493441-5A91-11CF-8700-00AA0060263B} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)). 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {91493441-5A91-11CF-8700-00AA0060263B} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).

ASP.NET is not authorized to access the requested resource. Consider granting access rights to the resource to the ASP.NET request identity. ASP.NET has a base process identity (typically {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5 or Network Service on IIS 6 and IIS 7, and the configured application pool identity on IIS 7.5) that is used if the application is not impersonating. If the application is impersonating via <identity impersonate="true"/>, the identity will be the anonymous user (typically IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the authenticated request user. 

To grant ASP.NET access to a file, right-click the file in Explorer, choose "Properties" and select the Security tab. Click "Add" to add the appropriate user or group. Highlight the ASP.NET account, and check the boxes for the desired access.

Source Error: 


Line 12:         ' Create an instance of PowerPoint, make it visible,
Line 13:         ' and open Pres1.ppt.
Line 14:         Dim oPP As New PowerPoint.ApplicationClass()
Line 15:         oPP.Visible = MsoTriState.msoTrue
Line 16:         Dim oPresSet As PowerPoint.Presentations = oPP.Presentations


Source File: G:\Projects\PPTTest\Default.aspx.vb    Line: 14 

Stack Trace: 


[UnauthorizedAccessException: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {91493441-5A91-11CF-8700-00AA0060263B} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).]
   _Default.PPT() in G:\Projects\PPTTest\Default.aspx.vb:14
   _Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in G:\Projects\PPTTest\Default.aspx.vb:8
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +91
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +74
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2207
```

Please someone help me out of this situation. I am using windows server 2008, Visual Studio 2010 with ASP.NET Framework 4.0, , using form based authentication.

Thank you

Comment: hmmm... anyone here who can sort this out or if didn't understand the problem then discuss it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it has been resolved by giving permissions to "This User" and then give you login credentials  in COM+ settings.